# How to move data from one table into an EAV structure in MySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mariadb, entity-attribute-value

I am new at php/mysql and as a project for myself to learn programming i am trying to create a sort of price comparison engine in php on Xampp.

Currently i am working on the import end.I want to import merchant feeds into an EAV designed database (Mariadb). I am trying to move data from a temporary (tmp) table to 3 other tables. The merchant feed data is loaded into 'tmp' and needst to be moved to the other tables.

What i have is this:

tmp (temporarily dump of csv file)

```
tmp.ean

tmp.isbn

tmp.color

tmp.dimensions

tmp.image

tmp.upc

tmp.price

tmp.stock

tmp.merchant
```

t1  (basic product info table)

```
t1.ean (unique)

t1.isbn

t1.upc
```

t2 (price and stock table)

```
t2.ean (FK)

t2.price

t2.stock

t2.merchant
```

t3 (attributes table)

```
t3.ean (FK)

t3.color

t3.dimensions

t3.image
```

Currently i have the code for filling t1

**Fill t1 with data from tmp**

1) I am first copying ean column from tmp.ean to t1.ean to add new products. 
2) on a second run the i am filling the columns t1.isbn and t1.upc with data from tmp table, where tmp.ean = t1.ean.
This part works, unique products are added to t1 table.

What I want to do is also add the data to T2 and T3, in these tables ean is not unique as there can be more attributes per ean and more prices (merchants) per ean
I am thinking to do as following:

**Update prices/stock in t2:**

1) Add tmp.ean to t2.ean where not exsist EAN and Merchant. So add ean when no ean present with that ean and merchant id
2) Add tmp.stock tmp.price to t2.stock t2.price where tmp.ean = t2.ean AND tmp.Merchant is t2.merchant

**Update attributes in t3:**

1) Add tmp.ean to t3.ean where not exsist EAN and t3.color (entity). So add ean when no ean present with that attribute (color)
2) add tmp.color (value) to t3.color where tmp.ean = t3.ean AND tmp.color = t3.color

Am i on the right path? Or am i making things too complex and is there an easier/faster way to do this, and which sql query commands are best to use, UPDATE, INSERT, JOIN? There might be millions of products and many imports so speed will become an issue.

Comment: i once wrote a answer on [stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51256/how-to-store-schema-less-data-efficiently-in-a-relational-database/51286#51286) about storing EAV in SQL (MySQL) ,, i think MariaDB's [Dynamic Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns/) or MySQL innoDB's [InnoDB memcached Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html) are the best options if you want to keep using a SQL server..

Comment: Hoi Raymond, thanks for the anwer, I will look into your suggestions. As mentioned I am a beginner, hence I think it might be best for me to check dynamic columns first. I have been thinking about NoSQL solution too, but I think I currently lack the skills for that. A lot of information and sample code can be found on MySQL/MariaDB, so I can fiddle myself and adjust myself without constantly having to invent or ask for the correct syntaxes.

As I understand with Dynamic Columns you basically create virtual columns per row, so it doesn't matter if you have 1 or 50 attributes.

Comment: and top off that MariaDB has the CONNECT engine which can directly query some NoSQL databases like MongoDB, if you want to use NoSQL.

Comment: *"As I understand with Dynamic Columns you basically create virtual columns per row, so it doesn't matter if you have 1 or 50 attributes"* Yes indeed more or less as virtual columns is a wrong definition to use there, this is MariaDB's "real" [virtual columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/) which you can also use to index those dynamic columns.

Comment: Thanks, i will lookinto that too. Based on your comment i think i will look at dynamic columns for t3, and leave it as it is for t1 and t2.

Main point remains the procedure/flow for import. How do i automate without creating duplicates in t1 and t3, but allowing multiple ean in t2. But limit to only one ean per product per merchant. is there a correct order of steps, in my example i INSERT new EAN first and then UPDATE data to all rows. I this case can i better proceed with 'INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement' or 'join' statement for adding products to t1 and t2?

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB's Dynamic Columns are the precursor to JSON, which now exists in *recent* versions of both MySQL and MariaDB.

You hinted that you are getting EAV, but your example only shows `color` and `dimensions`.  A JSON string is handy for collecting a *variable* set of attributes (f-stop, dress size, engine_cylinders, calories, ...), but it is *not* handy for searching on any of those.  Things like color and size *might* be generic enough *and searched on enough* to warrant having their own columns.  This is the EAV [*compromise*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

When two tables have the *same* `PRIMARY KEY` (`ean`), it is rarely wise to keep them as two tables.  Instead, it is usually better to make a single table.

Yes, when loading data, it is usually wise to load into a temp table, then cleanse the data and move to other table(s).

Follow the [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) tag for lots more discussions.  You may find other tips useful for your project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and advice!

Just FYI the color and dimensions were just example, there would be 100

Comment: Reason I use multiple tables with same EAN is that for updating the price I am using 'load data infile'  which doesn't support update, but only replace.  So if I e.g. manually have to adjust attributes for a typo, it will all be lost when prices are "updated" (read: replaced).


I am learning as I go, if I find a better method I might change it in my educational project. For the moment I try to stick to standard PHP and MySQL, in order to keep it simple for me.